# which has better and smooth API for DOM manipulation? Chrome or firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, google-chrome, client-side

I am developing a web application which will collect, store and display the user feedback of google search results. For the user interface in client side, I need to hack the google's search page on client side to add some links, buttons, extract some data etc.

The firefox docs are very confusing. I also heard that chrome don't have a mature API to deal with extensive DOM manipulation. I am a very beginner to JavaScript. So please tell me which of the above browser have a easier and robust API to solve my problem?

Comment: Everyone will tell you to use a library and they will be right

Comment: Is using jQuery not an option? It provides unified access to stuff like this. Or are you doing this in something special like a browser extension?

Comment: My idea is to have the web app exposing REST api's to store and retrieve user feedback. And I should be able to access them from a browser. Yes a browser extension exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using JavaScript, both browsers have the same capabilities. In my experience, Chrome has better JavaScript performance than Firefox.

For your project, you may want to use GreaseMonkey scripts. It requires an add-on for Firefox, but Chrome runs them without requiring an add-on.

Another approach you may want to consider is using the Google Search API, rather than manipulating the DOM. This would allow you much greater flexibility.

Comment: Much thanks for introducing the google search API, I'll dig deep into it :)

Answer (score 2):

I can't see going wrong with either one but Firefox has always been highly programmable with years of emphasis on its ability to manipulate the DOM. An example of this is XUL, Prism, and its long use of add-ons. So if I had to pick ONE, I'd choose Firefox.